# AWS retrieve Storage Class tier for all files in EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-efs

How can I, preferable through the AWS CLI, retrieve the current Storage Class tier (Standard, Standard IA etc) of a file (or even better ALL files) that is stored in EFS.
I would like to perform some analysis of the file types and their Storage tiers.
I know that you can do that easily for objects in S3, but how about EFS ones?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's possible (at this time) to see that per-file.